# Some fields missing from the kibana “terms” options

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a "message" field which is not appearing in kibana when I select aggregation by "Terms" and open the "Field" drop-down.

Sadly I'm a pre-beginner at ES but I'm guessing it might have something to do with the mappings. Here is the beginning of the result of the query "GET logstash-2017.02.17" (does it have something to do with the "message_field" section?):

```
{
  "logstash-2017.02.17": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true,
          "norms": false
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "message_field": {
              "path_match": "message",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "string_fields": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
```

As you may have guessed the data is all coming in via logstash. In most cases the message field seems to be created by default when you use the logstash grok filter. However I have other logstash pipelines where I specifically assign data to the message field.

Comment: you may just need to go into kibana settings and hit the reload button there if it was added to the index after you added it to kibana initially

Comment: No it's been there all along. I've been feeding it data for a couple of days already. I refreshed it the indexes now anyway just to double-check, but no...

Comment: If you could show your logstash conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [on the elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/some-fields-missing-from-the-kibana-terms-options/75559/2).